# Bind @PostMapping to multiple parameters instead of model bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using `@GetMapping`, I could bind each get-query parameter to one method parameter with `@RequestParam` annotation.
The following does not work, it would only be valid with `@GetMapping`:

```
//@PostMapping("/search")
@GetMapping("/search")
public void search(@RequestParam String origin, @RequestParam destination) {

}
```

Question: how can I achieve the same with `@PostMapping`?

Or do I always have to use a model bean like:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
public void search(@RequestBody model) {

}
```

Comment: when you have XML or JSON content in the request body it is better to create a model. Using model, you can also handle nested elements easily (model inside a model).

Comment: There are differences between `GET` and `POST` on how the data is passed. Using `POST`, it is in the body of the request and using `@ReqeustBody` makes sense. If you are using `GET`, then using `@RequestParam` to get query parameters or `@PathVariable` to get URL template variable makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The two ways are different, if the payload contains an object representing a serializable entity you should go for the second way and let jackson handle the deserialization for you, if not you can use the first one or you can build an entity for that , both works